# Is maven JAR runnable on hadoop?

Tags: maven, hadoop, mapreduce

To produce jar from hadoop mapreduce program(mapreduce wordcount example) i used maven.
Here i successfully done 'clean' and 'install'.
Also 'build' successfully by running as a Java Application by including arguments(input and output). 
And it provided expected  result successfully.
Now the problem is not running on hadoop. 
Giving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount
```

Is maven JAR runnable on hadoop?

Comment: Maven is a build tool which creates a Java Artifact. Any JAR containing the hadoop dependencies and the main program with fully qualified class having main() method in the Manifest file should be working with the hadoop.

Comment: Is `WordCount` in a package?

Comment: WordCount is the class which contains "main" function.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a build tool which creates a Java Artifact. Any JAR containing the hadoop dependencies and the class having main() method in the Manifest file should be working with the hadoop.

Try running your JAR using the below command

```
hadoop jar your-jar.jar wordcount input output
```

where "wordcount" is the name of the class with main method,"input" and "output" are the arguments.

Comment: "hadoop jar C:\Users\asus\Desktop\wc\target\wc-0.0.1.jar WordCount \input\a.txt \WordCountOutput" it was the command.

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1) I think you are missing the package details before the classname. Copy your package name and put it before the classname and it should work.

`hadoop jar /home/user/examples.jar com.test.examples.WordCount /home/user/inputfolder /home/user/outputfolder`

PS: If you are using a jar for which the source code is not available with you, you can do

`jar -tvf /home/user/examples.jar`

and it will print all the classses with their folder names. Replace the "/" with "." (dot) and you get the package name. But this needs JDK (not JRE) in the PATH.

2) You are trying to run a MapReduce program from a Windows prompt. Are you sure you have Hadoop installed on your Windows?

Comment: Hadoop is installed but the command &quot;hadoop -version&quot; provides the of the java version like &quot;JDK_1.8_45&quot;.
is this the problem?

Comment: `hadoop version` command doesn't print any java information as far as I know.

Comment: how to fix this?